# IE conditional comments doesn't apply on every versions targeted

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, conditional-comments

So i would like to redirect some IE users to a specific page. While it is working on IE 7 and 8, according to NetRender and Browserstack, it's not on IE 6 and 9. I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.rudaz.ch/old-browsers/";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I've also tried to target each version one by one like this:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.rudaz.ch/old-browsers/";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

And all at ones doing this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.rudaz.ch/old-browsers/";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

But the results are the same.
I've also tested it by emulating IE 6 with WineBottler.

Comment: It's possible this is just an issue with browserstack / netrenderer. You could try downloading a free IE virtual machine from Microsoft to try it out yourself? https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

Comment: The problem is still there. I've just discovered that IE 11 on windows 7 is also redirected. Is it possible that it's detected as a lower version since it's a windows 7 version?